# Estimating the blood circulation around the epicondyles of the humerus

Tags: quantified-self, home-medical-equipment, epicondylitis, blood-circulation

Decreased microcirculation has been shown to contribute to the lateral epicondylitis symptoms (1). Is there any home medical equipment that a patient suffering from epicondylitis could use to estimate the blood circulation around the lateral and medial epicondyles of the humerus? The article uses [Laser Doppler Flowmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_Doppler_velocimetry), which is a non-invasive method to estimate the blood flow (2), but it doesn't look very affordable. The goal is for the patient to quantify to what extent some activities or food increases his blood circulation.

---

(1) Oskarsson, Eva, et al. "[Decreased intramuscular blood flow in patients with lateral epicondylitis](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=18037342224490754332&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)." Scandinavian journal of medicine & science in sports 17.3 (2007): 211-215.

(2) Fredriksson, Ingemar, Carina Fors, and Johannes Johansson. "[Laser doppler flowmetry-a theoretical framework.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=12265497875503709806&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)" Department of Biomedical Engineering, Linköping University (2007).

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://redd.it/68gauq
- http://qr.ae/TwjxWo